Why was Sara informed about having a baby just months before she would've found out on her own?
In Parshas Vayeira, a Malach told Avraham that he and Sara will have a baby in a year. But Sara was anyway going to find out about the baby several months later, when she would realize the pregnancy. So why was it so important for Hashem to inform Sara several months before she would've found out on her own?

So she could start taking prenatal vitamins

@DoubleAA - can you elaborate on that? Couldn't Hashem have just made it where she didn't need the vitamins? Also, were there vitamins back then?

Probably so she’d know this was Hashem’s plan all along. If it stam happened, she might’ve thought this was just the lucky day finally

I don't really understand the question. If you had good news, would you keep it to yourself? If you could make a barren woman happy, would you opt to not tell her she's finally pregnant?

Maybe Abraham and Sarah had stopped having sex, due to their infirmity. The announcement was made so they would know to resume.

@ClintEastwood But during the first three months תשמיש קשה לולד, and after that (when it's good for the baby) she'd already know she's pregnant.

The news about Sarah's pregnancy were given to Avraham on the day he was commanded to have bris millah. The angels visited him on either the same day or one the 3rd day afterwards. The Torah Bereshis 18:11 states that Sarah could no longer have children (also see Rashi):

Now Abraham and Sarah were old, advanced in years; Sarah had stopped having her periods.

Note that this verse is out of order (see syntactic rule here) since its subject precedes the verb which is in the simple past tense (קל). Immediately prior to the verse (i.e. after the verse chronologically), once the angels came, Rashi on Bereshis 18:8 states

ויקח חמאה וגו AND HE TOOK חמאה, ETC. — but he (Avraham) did not bring bread, on account of Sarah becoming mentstruant; as the 'way of women' returned to her that day, and the dough became impure (Bava Metzia 87a).

Therefore, the angels informed Sarah immediately once they cured her so that she could conceive. Informing her prophetically prior to that could also suggest to her that she might be giving birth unnaturally, which would put her life in big danger and add unnecessary stressful feelings. Also, we see that both Sarah's ability to conceive and the news of her upcoming pregnancy and giving birth and were contingent on Avraham passing the test of bris millah.
